# Firebase, save data in a unique key

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function, and I'm trying to save the data inside the child ('Alunos"), in a unique key. I tried, but I couldn't save with the key

salvarDados() {

```
    ... data ...

    firebase.database().ref('Usuarios').child(idUsuario).child('Alunos') "UNIQUE KEY" .set({
        imagem,
        nome,
        idade,
        altura,
        peso
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a unique key, call `push()` instead of `set`():

```
firebase.database().ref('Usuarios').child(idUsuario).child('Alunos').push({
    imagem,
    nome,
    idade,
    altura,
    peso
})
```

For more on this, see:

- The Firebase documentation on [appending to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data)
- The Firebase blog on [the reasoning and working of these so-called push IDs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)
- The Firebase blog on [best practices when using arrays with Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)